# Horizontal Drop Down Menu keeps moving...how do I get it to stay put?

Tags: html, css, position

I am a dropdown menu noob, and I can't seem to figure out how to keep my dropdown menu from blowing out and moving the main buttons. I'm sure its some kind of positioning adjustment, but I can't figure out where and what it is. Here is the jfiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/F4WvT/

Here is the html:

```
<div id="global-nav">
<ul>
        <li><a href="#A">HOME</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#B">ABOUT</a>
          <div id="global-subnav">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#A">Sub Category 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#B">Sub Category 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#C">Sub Category 3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#D">Sub Category 4</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#E">Sub Category 5</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#F">Sub Category 6</a></li>                     </ul>
           </div>
         </li>
                     <li><a href="#B">CONTENT</a>
          <div id="global-subnav">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#A">Sub Category 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#B">Sub Category 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#C">Sub Category 3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#D">Sub Category 4</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#E">Sub Category 5</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#F">Sub Category 6</a></li>                     </ul>
           </div>
         </li>
        <li><a href="#A">CONTACT</a>
        </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
<style type="text/css">
#global-nav {
width: 180px;
height: 40px;
background-image: none;
float: left;
position: static;
margin-left:0px;
}

#global-nav a {
color:#000;
font-size:12px;
cursor:pointer;
display:block;
width: 200px;
height: 40px;
text-align:center;
vertical-align: central;
text-decoration:none;
font-weight:bold;
}

#global-nav ul {
background: whitesmoke;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;

}

#global-subnav ul{
background: #D3171A;
position: relative;
    width: 250px;
        text-align:center;
left: 180px;
top: -55px;
}

#global-nav li {
list-style: none;
border-bottom: none;
border-width: 0px;

}

#global-nav ul ul li {
display:none;

}

#global-nav li:hover {
background: none;
}

#global-nav li:hover ul li {
display:block;
}
</style>
```

How do I get this my main nav buttons to stay still? Good karma for quick advice!

Answer (score 0):

You need to make your sub navigation positioned absolute to it's relative parent, which in your case has to be the `<li>` element. Setting a `top: 0` of your sub navigation element, will position it at the top of its parent, which is exactly what you want.

Edited example of your code: [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/F4WvT/2/)

Comment: Close...that keeps the main buttons static, but I need the sub categories to align to the top of their respective button rather than all of them aligning absolute to the top...so the "about" subcategory buttons would open with the top aligning next to "about" button...same with content.

Answer (score 0):

```
#global-subnav ul {
background: #D3171A;
position: relative;
width: 250px;
text-align: center;
left: 0px;
top: 0;
}
```